# searching in multiple collections joined by common fileds in xquery marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have two collections('A' and 'B') with millions of transport insurance data documents. The two collections have four elements in common(customer-no, date-of-insurance, insurance-no,accident-number)  and one element(license-no) exists only in one collection('A'). I want to extract all the documents that are present in both the collections and also have the element of collection'A'. I am able to retrieve all the customer-nos from 'A' with cts-search. Then I loop through each of these customer-nos to look for license-no in 'A'. It gives an empty sequence. But I know this is not possible. Could someone guide me with appropriate search logic?

```
    let $col-A :=  cts:search(
   doc(),
    cts:and-query((
         cts:collection-query('col-A'),
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('abc:Acusno'), '*', (("wildcarded")))

    )))

  for $each in $col-A
  let $col-B := cts:search(doc(),
      cts:and-query((cts:collection-query('col-B'),
     cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('abc:Bcusno'), $each)
   )))

 return $col-B
```

returns empty sequence

Answer (score 1):

Your first cts:search is returning entire documents, which you are then passing in as argument into the value-query. You probably want to pass in just the value of `abc:Acusno`. You could do that with something like `$each//abc:Acusno`.

Your code is not using a very efficient approach though, and what if certain Acusno values occur multiple times?

I would recommend putting a range index on `abc:Acusno`, and using [`cts:values`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values) to pull up the unique values that match a given query. Then feed that entire list as one argument without any looping to a query against `abc:Bcusno`. You don't have to use a range index, and range query on Bcusno, but it could be useful to have that index anyhow. The code would then look something like this:

```
let $query :=
  cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query('col-A'),
    cts:element-query(xs:QName('abc:Acusno'), cts:true-query())
  ))

let $customerNrs :=
  cts:values(
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("abc:Acusno")),
    (),
    (),
    $query
  )

return cts:search(
  collection(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query('col-B'),
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('abc:Bcusno'), '=', $customerNrs)
  ))
)
```

Note: be careful when returning full search lists like this. You might want to paginate the response.

HTH!

Comment: It could also be worthwhile to have a look at OpticAPI. Queries like these are a good fit for it: https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI